# discord.py weird problem with embed's set_image() function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been developing a Discord bot with discord.py for a while and have found myself frequently using embeds and setting their images with the set_image() function to access image data from various sites. for example:
`embed.set_image(url='https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/large/{}.jpg'.format(pokemon.name.lower()))`
 to set the image to that of the requested pokemon.

My most recent endeavor has been to create a command to display a Minecraft player's skin/head given their username. My code:

```
@bot.group(pass_context = True, aliases = ['minecraft'])
async def mc(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Error!', 
        description = ':x: Please specify a subcommand!',
        color = 10891826
        )
        await bot.say(embed = embed)






@mc.command()
async def head(username = None):
    if username is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Error!', 
        description = ':x: Head not found! Did you spell the username right? It is case-sensitive.',
        color = 10891826
        )
        await bot.say(embed = embed)
    else:
        http_conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.mojang.com")
        http_conn.request("GET", "/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username,
            headers={'User-Agent':'Minecraft Username -> UUID', 'Content-Type':'application/json'})
        response = http_conn.getresponse().read().decode("utf-8")

        if (not response): 
            return ""

        json_data = json.loads(response)
        try:
            uuid = json_data['id']
        except KeyError as e:
            print("KeyError raised:", e)

        embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Head of {}'.format(username),
        color = 53380
        )
        embed.set_image(url = 'https://crafatar.com/avatars/{}.jpg'.format(uuid))
        await bot.say(embed = embed)





@mc.command()
async def skin(username = None):
    if username is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Error!', 
        description = ':x: Skin not found! Did you spell the username right? It is case-sensitive.',
        color = 10891826
        )
        await bot.say(embed = embed)
    else:

        http_conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.mojang.com")
        http_conn.request("GET", "/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username,
            headers={'User-Agent':'Minecraft Username -> UUID', 'Content-Type':'application/json'})
        response = http_conn.getresponse().read().decode("utf-8")

        if (not response): 
            return ""

        json_data = json.loads(response)
        try:
            uuid = json_data['id']
        except KeyError as e:
            print("KeyError raised:", e)

        embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Skin of {}'.format(username),
        color = 53380
        )
        embed.aet_image(url = 'https://crafatar.com/renders/body/{}.jpg'.format(uuid))
        await bot.say(embed = embed)
```

Everything works fine for some usernames, but for others, the image simply doesn't show up. Some odd cases even work for the head command but not the skin command (or vice versa). I've noticed after much experimenting that swapping the extension from .jpg to .png fixes the issue for the ones that don't work, and stop the ones that previously worked from working. Inputting the values manually into the crafatar site (with any extension or even with no extension at all) yields a valid direct image link, but for some reason, it won't load into the embed. It doesn't give me any error or exception, so I can't solve this by excepting and changing it to .png in the except statement, leaving me lost. If anyone knows why this is happening or what I can do to fix it, I'll be very grateful. I'm probably just being stupid but I've spent way too long on this, all I've dug up online are people forgetting to use kwargs (ie `set_image('url')` rather than `set_image(url='url'`), and it's making my brain hurt.

Note: I am not using the rewrite version of discord.py and I don't intend to port my entire bot over to it so please don't suggest that

Comment: You mentioned that removing the extension allows you to get the image in the browser.  Have you tried doing that in `set_image`?

Comment: I had actually tried that originally, and none of my testing usernames worked without a file extension, so I assumed that an extension was necessary as I'd never used it without one before.